# ¿Cuando en CSS3 es imprescindible utilizar etiquetas propias de cada navegador -moz-, -webkit-, -ms-, -o-?

Tags: css, css3

Entiendo que hay funciones de CSS, como `gradient` que no son soportadas en algunos de los navegadores más antiguos. Me he encontrado con este ejemplo:

```
#grad {
    background: red; /* Para navegadores que no soportan Gradient */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* Para Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* Para Opera 11.1 - 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* Para Firefox 3.6 - 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* Sintaxis standard */
}
```

Si lo entiendo bien: `background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);` no funcionaría en ninguno de esos navegadores para los que se ha especificado una declaración con etiqueta de su propio navegador. ¿Eso es verdad? Otra pregunta: si escribo lo siguiente:

```
background-color: blue;
-moz-background-color: red;
```

El resultado será que ¿en Mozilla el fondo será rojo y en los demás azul? Y una ultima pregunta: cuando escribís CSS ¿cómo sabéis cuando es imprescindible utilizar etiquetas propias de cada navegador ó cuando basta escribir una sola declaración?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Si lo entiendo bien: background: linear-gradient(red, yellow); no
> funcionaría en ninguno de esos navegadores para los que se ha
> especificado una declaración con etiqueta de su propio navegador. ¿Eso
> es verdad?

Si.

> El resultado será que ¿en Mozilla el fondo será rojo y en los demás
> azul?

Si. Dependendiendo que cual prefijo utilizes, sera aplicado en un navegedor u otro.

> ¿cómo sabéis cuando es imprescindible utilizar etiquetas propias de
> cada navegador ó cuando basta escribir una sola declaración?

Puedes investigarlo en la pagina [can i use](https://caniuse.com/#home) donde da con lujo de detalles en que navegadores es soportado cierta regla css y si necesita algun prefijo. Por ejemplo con [grandient](https://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient) dice que no es requerido el prefijo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque seria justo decir que el uso de prefijo esta siendo eliminado lentamente. Personalmente no lo utilizo mucho desde hace un tiempo y funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 1):

Los navegadores implementan, muchas veces, sus propios estándares basados en características no del todo aprobadas por la **W3C**, por esto es necesario el uso de prefijos en algunas propiedades CSS.

Lo que hago yo para saber que propiedad necesita prefijos, cual no necesita y cual es soportada o no soportada por cierto navegador es revisar dicha propiedad en los siguientes links:

[http://shouldiprefix.com](http://shouldiprefix.com/)

[caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/)

Otra forma de resolver este tipo de problema es usar la librería de JavaScript [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) la cual agrega el prefijo del navegador actual a una propiedad css sólo cuando es necesario